# Why my HTTP Post request not reading data from payload?

Tags: python, api, http-post

I am writing the following code but the post request is not printing the given data in the interface console. Could you please help me with it?

```
import requests
pyload = {'id': 2,
        'Desc': IT}
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/ncc',data = pyload)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)
print(res.url)
```

Comment: `request is not loading the given data` - what does it mean? Error in your response?

Comment: The data in "pyload" is not getting printed in interface console.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json` instead:

```
pyload = {'id': 2, 'Desc': IT}
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/ncc', json=pyload)
```

Answer (score 0):

data is a string

```
import json

...
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/ncc',data = json.dumps(pyload))
```